# What font is this? (Android)

Tags: font-identification, android

[image]

Is this a system font on Android or custom one? Results from [font identication sites](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/) seem to indicate it's a custom one not natively present on android?

Answer (score 1):

It's Lato - a SIL Open Font - https://fontlibrary.org/en/font/lato

[image: Sample of Lato]